# jQuery - select children on the same level (odd or even)

Tags: jquery, css, recursive-descent

is there a way to replace following CSS with jQuery?

```
.quote-body .quote-body { background: #f5f5f5 }
.quote-body .quote-body .quote-body { background: #fff }
.quote-body .quote-body .quote-body .quote-body { background: #f5f5f5 }
.quote-body .quote-body .quote-body .quote-body .quote-body { background: #fff }
...
and so on
```

Comment: is he question about unlimited nesting of .quote-body elements ? .. slightly baffled at the css

Answer (score 5):

Something like this might work:

```
$('.quote-body').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass($(this).parents('.quote-body').size() % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even');
});
```

For every .quotebody element, find the number of parent elements that has the class .quotebody and take modulo of two to define odd or even.

**EDIT**

Tested and working beautifully. This method might be a bit sluggish on complicated documents as for every element, jQuery has to traverse all the way back to the root element. But it works.

Working example: http://www.ulmanen.fi/stuff/oddevenchild.php

Comment: I tried something similar, setting odd and even classes, but making the class dependent of the parent's class. If the parent is odd, $(this) must be even. It depends a lot on the order in which $(".quote-body") finds/returns elements though

Comment: Remember to tick the answer as correct if you found this useful :)

Comment: Sander, I thought of something like that too, but you'd had to first find the elements which have no parent .quote-bodies, and then select their immediate children etc.. And the child .quote-bodies might not be *immediate* children, so that would complicate things more.. :) This method might be slow, but at least it's short.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a simple selector that could solve this, but you may be able to achieve the intended results using a while loop:

```
var $quotes = $(<containing-elem>).children(".quote-body"), level = 0;

while($quotes.length > 0) {
    $quotes.css("background-color", (level % 2 ? "#f5f5f5" : "#fff"));
    level += 1;
    $quotes = $quotes.children(".quote-body");
}
```

To ensure that you don't initially select too many `.quote-body` elements, I'm first selecting the `.quote-body` elements that are immediate children of the containing element.

Comment: This will only recurse into the first child of the first child, etc.

Comment: That is not true.  The `children` function returns a all immediate children of the currently selected element, not just the first.  The script I posted is tested and it does work.  I'll upload an example page when I get home.

Comment: OK, you're right, sorry about that. I was confused because .children doesn't *appear* to select the children of all matched elements (which it indeed does)

Comment: No worries.  It's hard being a human compiler =P.  In any case, here's the working example I promised: http://www.the-xavi.com/static/quotes.html